My emacs doesn't run my init file, how can I solve?
I wrote the emacs configuration file in Elisp. But when I restart Emacs it comes back from scratch as if I hadn't configured it, but the configuration file continues in .emacs.d/init.el.
So I don't know what else to do, here's the configuration code:
(setq inhibit-startup-message t) 
(setq visible-bell t) ; Alertas 
(setq initial-buffer-choice 'debmx-new-buffer)
(setq initial-major-mode 'prog-mode)

(set-fringe-mode 15) 

(load-theme 'tango-dark t) ; 
(global-display-line-numbers-mode t) 
(column-number-mode t)  
(global-hl-line-mode t) 
(global-visual-line-mode t) 
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("." . "~/saves"))) 

(tool-bar-mode -1)
(menu-bar-mode -1) 
(scroll-bar-mode -1)
(tooltip-mode -1)

I reviewed all the code, rewrote it twice, uninstalled Emacs and installed it again, I looked to see if it had another initialization file but I saw that it didn't... I use MS Windows I used the command C -h v user-init-file and discovered that emacs is looking for my init file in the wrong path, so I changed the folder name of the original file, but it remained the same`error.
Emacs was looking in the c:/Users/55419/AppData/Roaming/.emacs folder, but that folder doesn't exist, so I renamed the /.emacs.d folder but it didn't help

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Perhaps there is a ~/.emacs or ~/.emacs.el.  You can delete them if you want to use ~/.emacs.d/init.el instead.

Thanks for the answer, but I looked and couldn't find it, I don't understand why emacs doesn't start directly with my configuration...

After you start Emacs, do C-h v user-init-file to find out the value of that variable. Then edit your question and add that information.

Also read how Emacs finds your init file and Windows HOME and see if it helps.

I used the command C -h v user-init-file and discovered that emacs is looking for my init file in the wrong path, so I changed the folder name of the original file, but it remained the same error...

You say "Emacs was looking in the c:/Users/55419/AppData/Roaming/.emacs folder ..." - that is wring: Emacs  was looking for that FILE, not for a folder of that name and it apparently found it, which is why it chose to use it.

It sounds like you made a directory named .emacs in your HOME. (Which on Unix systems is written concisely as ~/.emacs, so I will do so here even though you use Windows.)
However, Emacs looks for a file by that name, not a directory. As stated in the manual:

Emacs looks for your init file using the filenames ~/.emacs.el, ~/.emacs, or ~/.emacs.d/init.el in that order; you can choose to use any one of these names. (Note that only the locations directly in your home directory have a leading dot in the location’s basename.)

Notice also that it stops with the first one that it finds; if you have an empty file named ~/.emacs.el then the other two would be skipped even if they have your real configuration in them.

Thanks for the answer, after a long time I got it.
